# TensorFlow import error: TensorFlow import error

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, pip, artificial-intelligence, computer-science

I'm trying to getting start with tensorflow with this manual https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows all the installation complete successfully, i m using python 3.5.2 and latest version of pip, encountering this error, anyone explain me what should i do?

> enter code here Traceback (most recent call last): File    "C:\Users\parth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-p    tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 18, in    swig_import_helper return importlib.import_module(mname) File    "C:\Users\parth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\import    it__.py", line 126, in import_module return    _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) File "", line 986, in _gcd_import File "", line 969, in _find_and_load File "", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlo File    "", line 666, in _load_unlocked File    "", line 577, in module_from_spec File    "", line 906, in create_mod    File "", line 222, in    _call_with_frames_r ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application. During handling of the above exception, another    exception occurred: Traceback (most recent call last): File    "C:\Users\parth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-p    tensorflow\python__init__.py", line 66, in  from    tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow File    "C:\Users\parth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-p    tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 21, in     _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper() File "C:\Users\parth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-p    tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 20, in    swig_import_helper return    importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow') File    "C:\Users\parth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\import    it__.py", line 126, in import_module return    _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow' During handling of the above    exception, another exception occurred: Traceback (most recent call    last): File "", line 1, in  File    "C:\Users\parth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-p    tensorflow__init__.py", line 24, in  from tensorflow.python    import * File    "C:\Users\parth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-p    tensorflow\python__init__.py", line 72, in  raise    ImportError(msg) ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last): File    "C:\Users\parth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-p    tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 18, in    swig_import_helper return importlib.import_module(mname) File    "C:\Users\parth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\import    it__.py", line 126, in import_module return    _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) File "", line 986, in _gcd_import File "", line 969, in _find_and_load File "", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlo File    "", line 666, in _load_unlocked File    "", line 577, in module_from_spec File    "", line 906, in create_mod    File "", line 222, in    _call_with_frames_r ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application. During handling of the above exception, another    exception occurred: Traceback (most recent call last): File    "C:\Users\parth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-p    tensorflow\python__init__.py", line 66, in  from    tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow File    "C:\Users\parth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-p    tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 21, in     _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper() File "C:\Users\parth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-p    tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 20, in    swig_import_helper return    importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow') File    "C:\Users\parth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\import    it__.py", line 126, in import_module return    _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow' Failed to load the native    TensorFlow runtime. See    https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3do    arted/os_setup.md#import_error for some common reasons and solutions.    Include the entire stack trace above this error message when asking    for help.

Comment: You might want to re-paste your traceback, so it is more readable. There is a potential solution in the last comment here https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/97

Comment: Duplicate of this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43370953/error-while-import-tensorflow-module/43566463#43566463

Comment: It is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52864641/5072351) question. Follow the steps to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

[enter link description here](https://github.com/benoitsteiner/tensorflow-opencl/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/get_started/os_setup.md#test-the-tensorflow-installation)
when i update my vc_redist.x64 it will run perfect